# Connect to MSFT SQL Server using authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal

Tags: java, sql-server, azure

I am trying to connect to SQL server using **Azure Directory Service Principal**, but keep on getting the same error:

String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://<<>>.windows.net;databaseName=<<>>;user=;password=<<>>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal"

```
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Error connection to the database
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user <> in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal). javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:277)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthTokenPrincipal(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:112)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:5679)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5618)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5463)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:311)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:131)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6490)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:5068)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:5002)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7685)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4048)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3487)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3077)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2919)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1787)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1229)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at database.TestingDriverAndConnection.main(TestingDriverAndConnection.java:16)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:275)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:267)
    ... 20 more
```

Following the exact same details in ODBC or SSMS is working perfectly fine. Also setting
trustServerCertificate=true is not giving a different result.

This is the code I used to verify the connection: (reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;

public class AADServicePrincipal {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String principalId = "1846943b-ad04-4808-aa13-4702d908b5c1"; // Replace with your AAD service principal ID.
        String principalSecret = "..."; // Replace with your AAD principal secret.

        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setServerName("aad-managed-demo.database.windows.net"); // Replace with your server name
        ds.setDatabaseName("demo"); // Replace with your database
        ds.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal");
        ds.setUser(principalId); // setAADSecurePrincipalId for JDBC Driver 9.4 and below
        ds.setPassword(principalSecret); // setAADSecurePrincipalSecret for JDBC Driver 9.4 and below 

        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully logged on as: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the list of JARS that are present:

```
accessors-smart-2.4.9.jar
asm-9.5.jar
content-type-2.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.15.0.jar
jackson-core-2.15.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.15.0.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
json-smart-2.4.10.jar
lang-tag-1.7.jar
msal4j-1.13.8.jar
mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar
nimbus-jose-jwt-9.31.jar
oauth2-oidc-sdk-10.8.jar
slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar
```

SOLUTION: Turned out that it was not looking for the MSFT certificate but for Company specific certificate.

Comment: can you add part of your java code?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I have added the reference code, as well the jars that I have included.

Comment: your code is equal to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#connect-using-activedirectoryserviceprincipal-authentication-mode

have you checked the note? 'A contained user database must exist and a contained database user that represents the specified Azure AD principal or one of the groups the specified Azure AD principal belongs to, must exist in the database and must have the CONNECT permission (except for an Azure Active Directory server admin or group)'

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio that can't be the issue. Because from both SQL Server Management Studio as well ODBC I am able to connect using the ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio SOLUTION: Turned out that it was not looking for the MSFT certificate but for Company specific certificate.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick glad to see you resolved the issue by identifying **it was not looking for the MSFT certificate but for Company specific certificate.** posting the answer to help other community members.

As per this [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification/ba-p/2591304) by @Melania Nitu

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user <> in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal). javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

**This is an issue in Java Certificate Store.**

- The simple possible solution is enable **`TrustServerCertificate=True`** in the connection string when this option is enabled it will bypass the certificate validation and the connection succeeds.
- All the **certifications listed in this [document](https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm) should be imported**. after importing above certificates into the keystore cacerts, please use below command and please note **you must mention truststore and truststore password in the connection string to successfully connect.**

**Example of commands:**

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias TLS1 -file "C:\Users\Documents\Microsoft RSA TLS CA 01.crt" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\lib\security\cacerts"
```